# helpdesk ultimate magento extension

Tags: magento

does anyone knows why the link to Help Desk is not displaying in the user section of Magento?
Is there something I am missing?
I have installed correctly the extension, and on the back end I can see all the options are fine.
Also the help desk section in backend is fine, but nothing showing on the front end.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I suggest to ask this question to the extension's author - he is the one, who has the best skill to answer it. Otherwise, for the question to be answered at StackOverflow, it would be helpful to provide the link to the extension's page in the question, as the extension is not a standard or popular extension for Magento.

Comment: Another question that, although it could be twisted into a programming one, would be better served by a Magento StackExchange  site. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento

Comment: So, @AlanStorm, do you want some action to be performed, or did you left this note just FYI?

Comment: FYI, spreading word of the site so more people commit and become involved when the beta goes live.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure guess in the dark, but

1. Does the user you're logged in as have the ACL role for this menu?
2. If you're using an admin/super-user account, have you logged in and logged out?  This is sometimes necessary to rebuild the ACL roles, which are cached in the admin user's session object.